# Problem with Data URIs and CSS File Merge

Tags: magento-1.8, css, bug, regex

Magento CSS file merge is pretending the hostname to my data-uris because the RegEx in `Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package` (`beforeMergeCss`) does not work as expected. It should prepend hostname to relative image paths, but not to Data URIs.

```
$cssUrl = '/url\\(\\s*(?!data:)([^\\)\\s]+)\\s*\\)?/';
$contents = preg_replace_callback($cssUrl, array($this, '_cssMergerUrlCallback'), $contents);
```

CSS-Code:

```
background: #fafafa url("data:image/svg+xml;base64, PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iM3B4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNiAzIiBlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZD0ibmV3IDAgMCA2IDMiIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPjxwb2x5Z29uIHBvaW50cz0iNS45OTIsMCAyLjk5MiwzIC0wLjAwOCwwICIvPjwvc3ZnPg==") no-repeat;
```

Result after merge:

```
background: #fafafa url("http://shop12.dev/skin/frontend/shop/default/styles/data:image/svg+xml;base64")PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iM3B4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNiAzIiBlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZD0ibmV3IDAgMCA2IDMiIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPjxwb2x5Z29uIHBvaW50cz0iNS45OTIsMCAyLjk5MiwzIC0wLjAwOCwwICIvPjwvc3ZnPg==") no-repeat;
```

How to avoid this? I couldn't find out how to correct the synthax of the used RegEx. (Using a GIF is not a real solution to me)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In iphone.css magento also uses data URI but without quotes, try to do the same

```
background: #fafafa url(data:image/svg+xml;base64, PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgeD0iMHB4IiB5PSIwcHgiIHdpZHRoPSI2cHgiIGhlaWdodD0iM3B4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgNiAzIiBlbmFibGUtYmFja2dyb3VuZD0ibmV3IDAgMCA2IDMiIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPjxwb2x5Z29uIHBvaW50cz0iNS45OTIsMCAyLjk5MiwzIC0wLjAwOCwwICIvPjwvc3ZnPg==) no-repeat;
```

In your case instead of

```
/url\\(\\s*(?!data:)([^\\)\\s]+)\\s*\\)?/
```

you should use

```
/url\\(\\s*(?![\"\']?data:)([^)]+)\\)/
```

Comment: Sorry, I knew that. Problem is that the CSS-code is part of the foundation framework, which is linked to my project via bower. I surely could edit the code, but all my colleagues working on the project would have do the same. On every update. What would be the correct RegEx for all types (with single quotes, double quotes and without quotes)?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted.

Comment: This answer broke other css assets from being compiled. The other answer from @jblandry was what we ended up using that fixed everything.

Answer (score 4):

Actually this regexp covers more cases

```
/url\\(\\s*(?![\"\']?data:)(?!\%)([^\\)\\s]+)\\s*\\)?/
```

Especially this optimized svg data with gradients: http://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris

Comment: This answer FIXED ALL issues without breaking anything. The 'other' (currently accepted) answer fixed one thing but broke many others. This should be changed to  the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd the same issue (still present in Magento version 1.9.3.1) so I've created a module to solve this bug: https://github.com/just-better/magento1-css-merge-data-uri-fix

Comment: Still present in 1.9.3.4 (since 1.7.)