# Magento 1.9.3.x core issues and possible fixes?

Tags: magento-1.9, bug, magento-core, openmage

**Magento 1.9.3.7**

This is not a real question, just a compilation of known bugs in the latest Magento version.

I would like to have a complete list of known bugs, so that they can be fixed in Magento-LTS, if not by Magento itself.

Some I found here....

- [Default configuration value for serialized_array settings is ignored](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146978/default-configuration-value-for-serialized-array-settings-is-ignored/146981#146981) (since `1.9.3.0`)
- [Magento customer reset password customer_flowpassword error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167559/magento-customer-reset-password-customer-flowpassword-error/167944#167944) (since `1.9.3.0`)
- [Problem with Data URIs and CSS File Merge](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14973/problem-with-data-uris-and-css-file-merge) (since `1.7.0.0`)
- [Undefined variable: freePackageValue in Tablerate.php on line 130](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60743/undefined-variable-freepackagevalue-in-tablerate-php-on-line-130/60779#6077) (since `1.8.0.0`)
- [Customer VS persistent/customer templates](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183426/customer-vs-persistent-customer-templates) (since `1.6.0.0`)
- [Magento 1 is not showing Dataflow Profile History](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/170468/magento-1-is-not-showing-dataflow-profile-history/209318#209318) (since `...`)
- [Session validation failure in Magento 1 EE v 1.14.3.x (and CE 1.9.3.x)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167616/session-validation-failure-in-magento-1-ee-v-1-14-3-x-and-ce-1-9-3-x)  (since `1.9.3.0`)
- [Replace special characters (german umlauts)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95815/replace-special-characters-german-umlauts) (since `1.1.1`)
- ...

I know there's a lot more, but I don't have them all on the screen. **Therefore, please link contributions to real bugs here.**

**FYI:** [Magento-LTS](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts) is a community driven fork which accepts bugfixes and improvements (in some cases). The project is managed by some AoE people and some well-known names. It is not bloated with features that can be covered by extensions, but mainly refers to core bugs. In my opinion, the better alternative to the official version.

I use it myself and would like to fix as many bugs as possible. **It would be nice if you linked known problems here.**

**FYI2**: a small overview of what has already been fixed can be found here: [CHANGELOG](https://gist.github.com/sreichel/215a05b524ff2201e896e3273922d6bf) (not quite up-to-date)